# Android - Facebook sdk 3 Login

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, sdk

I followed exactly the guide for the minimum code: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

But it's not working. App runs normally, opens the dialog login, but after I press Ok button (or fill the fields login and password) to access public profile, no appears Hello 'username', both emulator and smartphone. I tried with fragments, and the same happens it :/

Comment: you need to sign your app in the facebook developers console

Comment: I did. I have app_id and put it in AndroidManifest.xml <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />

Comment: you should read step 5 [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/)

Comment: I did this too. But I went back to step 4 and I caught hash code using java code, and it's weird, but hash code is different when I used dos prompt to get it... I don't know why, anyway, it's working now! Tks for the help!